# If $f, g, h$ are continuous, then $f(g,h)$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, general-topology, limits, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k, g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be three continuous functions. Then, is $f(g(x),h(x))$ a continuous function?

I know that if $g$ and $f$ are continuous functions, then $g\circ f$ is a continuous function. However, the function in the question isn't a composition like this, so I am a bit confused. I proved in an exercise from the book I am using that $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is continuous if each component is continuous i.e. for every $i$ between $1$ and $p$, $f_i:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous where $f=(f_1, f_2, \dots, f_p)$. I'm not sure if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I proved in an exercise from the book I am using that $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is continuous if each component is continuous i.e. for every $i$ between $1$ and $p$, $f_i:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous where $f=(f_1, f_2, \dots, f_p)$.

Then you have everything you need. Define the function $\phi: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^2$ by
$$
\phi(x) = (g(x),h(x)).
$$
$\phi$ is continuous because its components are continuous. So, $f \circ \phi$ is continuous. We have
$$
f(\phi(x)) = f(g(x),h(x)),
$$
so we have reached the desired conclusion.